# Blogging Tool - AW Blog or WordPress Integration?

Tags: migration, third-party-module, wordpress, blog

I am looking into changing my current blog platform, which is the free AW blog edition. I have been quite disappointed with the level of customization and features with the free AW blog.

However, I have read a lot of horror stories with the Wordpress integration, where the blog stops working after a Magento update.

The Magento forum is down for maintenance, so I figured I would start the conversation here.

The other thing to keep in mind is that I have about 100 posts on the current AW blog platform, that I would need to transition over to Wordpress... Seems like a huge drag and potential SEO disaster with on-site links and changing URLs....

Has anybody else done this before? Is WP Blog integration worth the trouble?

Comment: FishPig's Wordpress integration seems to work pretty well. Recently we've tried the Magpleasure blog extension.  It seems to be fine.

Answer (score 3):

I have recently installed FishPig's extension on a Magento store, but have no experience with Magento upgrades yet in this regard. Upgrading Magento is never a piece of cake, though, is it?

If you can manage to migrate the content from AW blog to WordPress, I wouldn't worry about SEO too much. Just set up proper 301 permanent redirects and you should be fine. Organic traffic might go down for 1-2 weeks, but rankings normally are inherited and the traffic returns to normal after some time. That's at least what I experienced recently. And most importantly: keep blogging, that's what's even more important and that's so much more fun with WordPress ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can try `FishPig's Magento WordPress Integration Extension` which adds a basic link at the top nav bar in your magento site and manages the whole wordpress blog separately.
So, it won't be a headcahe.

```
http://fishpig.co.uk/magento/wordpress-integration/
```

Answer (score 1):

I can highly recommend FishPig's Magento WordPress Integration Extension. Not only is it a smooth integration but also they can help you setting it up and moving it to your site.

For my integration they helped with everything 
http://fishpig.co.uk/magento/wordpress-integration/

Even multiple instances is easily possible with that